# Exporting multiple output files using grep in Python

Tags: python, grep

I am creating a code in python which has to use grep and I am having problems with running it through grep. I start with an 'Infile' and then cut and sort that file to create 'Infile.ids'. The 'Infile.ids' contains unique ids which are in the 'Infile'. I then have to run the ids from the 'Infile.ids' line by line back through the 'Infile' and extract all lines with the ids into new separate files. The problem is when I run it in grep, it runs all the lines at once and basically gives me back a bunch of files that are identical to the original 'Infile' instead of seperate unique files.

These are example 'Infile' and output files I am trying to obtain.

```
Infile              Infile.ids    Infile.Hello     Infile.World      Infile.Adios
Hello 1 3 5 7       Hello         Hello 1 3 5 7    World 2 4 6 8     Adios 1 2 3 4
World 2 4 6 8       World         Hello a b c d    World e f g h     Adios i j k l
Adios 1 2 3 4       Adios
Hello a b c d
World e f g h
Adios i j k l
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

Infile = sys.argv[1]

os.system("cut -d \" \" -f1 %s | sort -u > %s.ids" % (Infile, Infile))
Infile2 = "%s.ids" % Infile

handle = open("%s.ids" % Infile, "r")
line = handle.readline()

for line in handle:
    os.system("grep \"%s\" %s > %s.%s" % (line, Infile, Infile, line))
    line = handle.readline()

handle.close()
```

Comment: "code in python which _has_ to use grep" -- care to explain why?

Comment: Might be a lot better to let Python itself handle all those matching statements you call in the shell. It's a bit of a discrimination towards Python's capabilities ;)

Comment: It is part of an assignment that involves using UNIX commands within Python. This part requires using grep and is the only part giving me problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over `handle`, every `line` will have a newline at the end, which the lines in the `Infile` obviously don't (they have the "1 3 5 7" stuff first). So that is why your grep is failing.

Try doing

```
for line in handle.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    os.system("grep \"%s\" %s > %s.%s" % (line, Infile, Infile, line))
```

And remove both the `line = handle.readline()` statements - if you are doing a `for` loop, it will iterate over the read lines itself. If you want to use the explicit reading call, then a `while` loop would be more appropriate (though I doubt recommended in this case).

Cheers